# cross-platform network interface enumeration

Tags: c, glib, gio

I need to enumerate local network interfaces (IPv4, IPv6), getting their addresses and netmasks. The code which should run both under Linux and newly under Windows (mingw64).

I was looking at [getaddrinfo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) which is somewhat cross-platform (both POSIX and [in ws2tcpip.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo)) but could not obtain the netmask part.

The Linux part currently uses [getifaddrs](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html). I am deciding whether to use native APIs (`getifaddrs` in Linux, [GetInterfaceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getinterfaceinfo) in Windows) or a cross-platform layer.

The code already uses [glib/gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.66/) heavily: does it have cross-platform layer for network interface enumeration?

Comment: I don't think GIO has anything for network enumeration -- just a basic connectivity checker, But I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: GLib/GIO does not have any network interface enumeration (cross-platform or other).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will write a wrapper function implemented for POSIX and Windows using native APIs.